# How can I setup STUN server in my socket.io video calling app?

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, stun, turn

I made a video calling app that can not make calls when clients are from different IP/network. I found a solution on the internet that I have to configure STUN/TURN server. But I was not able to do in my express js server-side code.

```js
const app = require("express")();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const cors = require("cors");




const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});

app.use(cors());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Running');
});



io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.emit("me", socket.id);

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        socket.broadcast.emit("callEnded")
    });

    socket.on("callUser", ({ userToCall, signalData, from, name }) => {
        io.to(userToCall).emit("callUser", { signal: signalData, from, name });
    });

    socket.on("answerCall", (data) => {
        io.to(data.to).emit("callAccepted", data.signal)
    });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: You said it makes a video call?  Using WebRTC? Can you show the relevant code that initialize WebRTC or your video call stack?  STUN is a configuration parameter to that stack.

Comment: @selbie : I have trouble like him. I am using server code as example of google tutorial -https://github.com/googlecodelabs/webrtc-web/tree/master/step-05 . But I dont know add the STUN/TURN. Can u give me some suggest. I'm fist work with server ( nodejs). My app client in Android working good with STUN/TUNR, now I am finding method for server side